# How to size a PageView inside a Column regarding its pages?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `PageView` inside a `Column`, like this:

```dart
....
  Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Page('Page 1'), 
          Page('Page 2'), 
          Page('Page 3'), 
        ]
      ),
      MyOtherWidget(),
    ]
....
```

But I get a render exception saying

> The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired: RenderViewport#b2888 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE:

If I wrap the `PageView` into an `Expanded` it all works fine, but then the `PageView` takes all the space left, placing `MyOtherWidget` to the bottom of the screen.

I wanted the `PageView` to take as litte space as possible, sizing itself according to `Page('Page 1')` size. I tried setting the `Column` to `MainAxisSize.min` but it didn't work, How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to use `Flexible` or `Expanded` widgets.

One solution is to wrap `MyOtherWidget` to  `Expanded` too and set flex.

```
     Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: PageView(children: <Widget>[
                Text('Page 1'),
                Text('Page 2'),
                Text('Page 3'),
              ]),
            ),
            Expanded(child: Text("Test"), flex: 10),
          ]),
```

`flex` - divide the remaining vertical space among the children with non-zero flex factors (e.g., those that are [Expanded]) according to their flex factor. For example, a child with a flex factor of 2.0 will receive twice the amount of vertical space as a child with a flex factor of 1.0.

Comment: I tried this already but it doesn't work, I have to fine tune the proportionality of the flex my self, I want it to be automatic according to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many methods either you can you sizedbox or exapanded. **But to use expaneded you have to use it without singleChildScrollView.**

Here is the example

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Text("asdfsadf"),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Text("asdfsadf"),
          ),
          Expanded(child: PageView(
            children: [
              Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text("Profile"),
              ),
              Container(
                // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                 color: Colors.blue,
                child: Text("Profile"),
              ),
              Container(
                // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                 color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Text("Profile"),
              ),
              Container(
                // height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width/2,
                 color: Colors.purple,
                child: Text("Profile"),
              )
            ],
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```